# SQL Server OPENQUERY against Postgres fails to return all records based on where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, linked-server

I'm running a remote query against a vendor maintained Postgres database.  The remote query is being run via a stored procedure in SQL Server.  My query is not returning all of the records it should.  If I add another column to the where clause then the query returns far more records.

I can't figure out why this is happening and I have a suspicion that I'm missing even more records.  Here is the SQL Server code.

**This executes almost immediately and returns 293 records and does *not* return itemid 865**

```
SELECT 
    itemid 
FROM 
    OPENQUERY(PostgresSource, '
        SELECT itemid 
        FROM items 
        WHERE 
            updated <= ''2018-10-16 23:59'' 
            AND updated > ''2018-10-07''  
    ')
```

**This executes in 14 seconds and returns 1,469 records and does return itemid 865!**

```
SELECT 
    itemid 
FROM 
    OPENQUERY(PostgresSource, '
        SELECT itemid 
        FROM items 
        WHERE 
            updated <= ''2018-10-16 23:59'' 
            AND updated > ''2018-10-07'' 
            AND itemid <> ''anythingcangohere''
    ')
```

My version info is

> PostgreSQL 9.5.3 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu
>   4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4, 32-bit

My colleague and I have been working on databases for years and we just can't figure this out.  To our minds adding a clause to the WHERE statement should not return *more* rows.  This is a vendor product so we don't have access to the box itself and we have limited SQL access.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

To allay concerns that my code above is not the actual code that causes issues here are screenshots.  I apologize for the blurring but I must blur the field names and table names.  There are no special characters or anything else but numbers and letters in the field or table names.  The screenshots show slightly different rowcounts than above because the source data changes and I took the screenshots roughly 24 hours after my original post.  Both the queries below were run within seconds of each other.

[image: 272 Rows]

[image]

Comment: You could intercept actual queries on PosrgreSQL side

Comment: Is it your actual query or simplified scenario? You could have misplaced `OR` condtition(common scenario).

Comment: The original query that caused problems was much larger but I reduced it as much as possible in order to post a concise question.  The code above are the actual queries that return different records but I changed the field and table names to obfuscate the actual vendor that supplied the database.

Comment: This is the actual code that returns different rows.  Running the code above causes the error.  The code above is as reproducible as possible without someone having access to our actual vendor database.

Comment: The issue might be related with nulls. There might be some nulls in 'itemid' column, and when null is compared with some value, the whole filter becomes void, and non-matching row can be included in the result. Can you check that?

Comment: Thanks for the idea!  There are no null values in the 'itemid' column and no null values in the 'updated' column.  I also manually validated many of the extra rows that came back and they should have been included in both queries.

Comment: `The original query that caused problems was much larger but I reduced it as much as possible` - please, take another look at the original query and what you've shown here: are there any joins, any ORs and parenthesis in WHERE clause, may be this query is actually composed from dynamic sql parts and so on.

Comment: Not the issue: `updated <= ''2018-10-16 23:59'' 
            AND updated > ''2018-10-07'' ` seems rather strange. Why not use a left-inclusive right-exclusive range: `updated >= ''2018-10-07'' 
            AND updated < ''2018-10-17''`

Comment: Hi Ivan, the query above causes the issue, no ORs or parenthesis anywhere in the WHERE clause. I know it's crazy but apart from changing the field names to the real field names the exact queries above cause issue.

Comment: I've added screenshots to the post showing me running the above code with Postgres returning incorrect results.

Comment: Stick an `EXPLAIN` in front of it and see if the execution plans tell you anything more. It could be a bug in the engine. It's unfortunate there's no direct access to the machine. You may want to escalate to the vendor to confirm these queries give the same results when not executed through `OPENQUERY` -- it's unlikely that's the problem, but still a possibility.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible to guess by watching on the screenshots. Code looks fine. Try asking your vendor.

Comment: From the screenshots you can't see if the same connection to the Sql Server is used in SMSS. And neither if the same connection is used for then PostgresSql.  But I assume the connections are the same.  It's also unknown if that OPENQUERY connects to a database cluster or a single instance.  Logically, if it connects to the same single postgres database then normally that 2nd query can only return equal or less rows. If not then their database(s) probably need some urgent maintainance. Like rebuilding indexes and stuff.

Comment: Is `updated` a timestamp field?